# Reading from binary files in C, Storing 32 bit machine instructions LEGv8

Tags: assembly, binary, disassembly, arm64

I've looked all around this site but can't find an answer that fits my problem. I need to read a binary file (which I am able to do) using fread() and save a 32 bit binary instruction (machine code) into an integer variable. I've tried to store read data into an unsigned char buffer array, which stores 2 4 bit hex chars into an array slot in the buffer, like this

```
unsigned char buffer[4];
fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), 4, ptr);
```

So this buffer[0-3] returns 91 00 0C 22.

This causes a problem where if I try to convert the hex digits to binary, I have trouble concatting lost 0's at the start a hex digit that is less than 8, for example 7 (111) needs to be concatted to the final 32 bit integer as 0111. I know I could probably add more code but there has to be a simpler way to just read 32 bits of machine code and directly store it into a int variable, or long long int if I need to. If you could help me understand what the fread function is doing when it reads machine code, so I can better understand how to store the data the way I want to, that'd be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, I forgot to mention that I am supposed to build a Disassembler, where I am given a machine code file filled with binaries and I'm supposed to convert them into assembly language statements printed to stdout. I need to get this basic read down so that I have a firm grasp on how to parse the binary file into 32 bit instructions. Thanks

Comment: So, I think you're looking for a 32-bit (4-byte) word that corresponds to those 4 bytes.  Figure out what endian you're using and consider that each byte is in base 256.  Then the 4-byte answer is something like (((((buffer[0]<<8) + buffer[1])<<8) + buffer[2])<<8)+buffer[3].  Each byte is the next digit in base 256.  We normally would simply call this a 4 byte value.

Comment: What do you mean by base 256. Is there any way I can just read 32 bits from the file and put it into an int variable with 32 1's or 0's?

Comment: I just told you one way to do that.  Each byte holds 1 of 256 values.  A digit in base 256.  So assemble them the way that 456 = 4x10^2 + 5x10^1 + 6x10^0.  Except using bytes as digits in base 256.

Comment: "If you could help me understand what the fread function is doing when it reads machine code" - `fread(...)` read data byte-by-byte. First byte in file would go into `buffer[0]`, second into `buffer[1]`, etc. If you want to read into `int variable`, than read directly into integer `uint32_t var; fread(&var, sizeof(var), 1, pFile);`